# UITableView ReloadData not using dequeued cells

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on an iOS RSS reader app.
My app implements a UITableView with custom section headers:

```
    UINib *sectionHeaderNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"HeadlineView" bundle:nil];
[self.newsTable registerNib:sectionHeaderNib forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];
```

Every section header is used to display an article title.
I have an option to change between the "already seen" articles and the new articles.
Every time I switch between the options, the table views data array is changed so I need to call UITableView ReloadData:

```
[self.newsTable performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

when I call this method it takes a bit more than 1 second to load (which seems stuck) because it reloads all the section headers instead of using dequeued section headers.
when I just scroll the table view everything works fine and the dequeue is working properly.

Every time I initialise a section header I set up 3 gesture recognizers and that's what takes a long time. but if the section header is dequeued, the gesture recognizers are already set so it is fast.

this is the dequeue code:

```
NowsHeadlineHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [self.newsTable dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];
```

I am not performing any other time consuming tasks in the cell/section loading.

Why is the tableview initialising the section header over and over again when I use reloadData and how can I fix this so it will be faster

Answer (score 0):

Forcibly calling `reloadData` wipes the slate clean on dequeued cells/headers/etc. From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData):

> Call this method (`reloadData`) to reload all the data that is used to
>   construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers,
>   index arrays, and so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays
>   only those rows that are visible. It adjusts offsets if the table
>   shrinks as a result of the reload.

If what you are doing is adding or substracting cells or sections, try using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` instead.

I also suspect your `NowsHeadlineHeaderView` set up is doing something inefficient, you might want to look into that.

Comment: so if my table consists of 50 sections, and now I want to change the table view to consist only 5 sections with completely different data, I have to delete 50 sections, and add 5 sections? I think this method will take even more time

Comment: @ItaiCaspi Well, yeah, there are edge cases for everything. But I will reiterate that I suspect you are doing some inefficient in your `NowsHeadlineHeaderView`, like possibly a synchronous network data load?

Comment: The NowsHeadlineHeaderView class is really simple, it only has 3 UILabels which I am updating from an array. it also has 3 gesture recognizers which are set up in the init block. thats it. so I am quite sure it's not causing the problem